# Avoid hitting the database multiple times Mongoid

Tags: mongoid

How can I prevent a criteria that's iterated & accessed multiple times from hitting the database multiple times?

Example with the following method in a Rails controller:

```
def current_somethings
  Something.limited
end
helper_method :current_somethings
```

Where the `Something` Model includes Mongoid::Document and the limited scope only includes some fields.

Mongoid will hit the database everytime I access `current_somethings` in controllers or views.

```
MONGODB (37ms) staging['somethings'].sort([[:name, :asc]])
MONGODB (31ms) staging['somethings'].sort([[:name, :asc]])
MONGODB (137ms) staging['somethings'].sort([[:name, :asc]])
MONGODB (38ms) staging['somethings'].sort([[:name, :asc]])
```

I've tried the [.cache method](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/extras.html) but it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

How can I prevent the same query from running multiple times? While, ideally keeping the ability to call additional methods on the criteria when needed.

Mongoid 2.6.0.